# Understanding concepts. Check if a member is static

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts, c++-templates

Lets say we have a simple concept like:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept MyConcept = requires {
    T::value == 42; 
};
```

In my understanding the concept says that, if the code `T::value == 42` is valid for the type T, I pass. So the `value` MUST be a static member, right?

I have a `struct`

```cpp
struct Test { int value = 0; }
```

and the next template function

```cpp
template <MyConcept T>
void call() { /*...*/ }
```

and when I try to do this:

```cpp
int main()
{
    call<Test>();
}
```

It works!

And the question is: why does it work?  `Test::value == 42` is not a valid code for the type `Test`.

I found a method to fix it like:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept MyConcept = requires {
    *(&T::value) == 42; 
};
```

And it "works" as expected:

```
<source>:6:20: note: the required expression '((* & T::value) == 42)' is invalid
```

And this concept works for the static `value` only, as it should be.
But why does the `T::value == 42` work?

godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/d3GPETEq9

UPD: + example https://godbolt.org/z/d8qfzK9b6

Comment: `T::value == 42;` seems mostly equivalent to `{ T::value } -> std::equality_comparable_with<int>;` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5K6YK16Mb).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> And this concept works for the static value only, as it should be. But why does the `T::value == 42` work?

Because there's actually an exception in the rule you think will cause this to fail.

The rule, from [[expr.prim.id.general]/3](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr#prim.id.general-3) is, emphasis mine:

> An *id-expression* that denotes a non-static data member or non-static member function of a class can only be used:
>
> - as part of a class member access in which the object expression refers to the member's class51 or a class derived from that class, or
> - to form a pointer to member ([expr.unary.op]), or
> - if that id-expression denotes a non-static data member and **it appears in an unevaluated operand**.
>
> [*Example 3*:
>
> ```
> struct S {
>   int m;
> };
> int i = sizeof(S::m);           // OK
> int j = sizeof(S::m + 42);      // OK
> ```
>
> — *end example]*

That third bullet right there: `T::value` is usable as an unevaluated operand. All the expressions you check in a requirement are unevaluated. So `T::value` works for non-static data members just fine.